# Excel File Upload issue in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, excel, oledb

I have a Application on which i'm uploading a Excel File and displaying the data inside a GridView.
My problems is now that, When I'm uploading the File gets uploaded. If the Data contains a MIX of Intergers and Text data, Text data's are not shown inside the Gridview and the DataSet on which im loading it.

```
public DataTable GetExcelData(string _FileName)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + _FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    string sheetname = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["table_name"].ToString();
    try
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetname + "]", connection);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        connection.Close();
        return ds.Tables[0]; ;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

This is code from which i'm loading the data onto the DataSet.

Ill show you an Example data

---

Column1

1. 1234
2. 2345
3. 4567
4. T123
5. 123Q
6. 6789

---

If we upload an Excel sheet with the Data Above it will only display it like this..

---

Column1

1. 1234
2. 2345
3. 4567
4. .
5. .
6. 6789

---

You can see in the Above T123,123Q is missing(it will be BLANK data). This is the Problem with my application when i'm Uploading an Excel sheet.

Has anyone come across a situation like this? Is there any way we can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this connection string... Its work fine now

This connection string is define by use its work for XLS

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + _FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"
```

For XLSX

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + _FileName +";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;'"
```